# AC to DC 12V 2A USB adapter

Tags: power-supply, power, usb

I have an external hard drive that I travel with to back up photos. It has a large (and quite heavy) AC/DC adapter that outputs 12V and 2A DC.

I'd like to be able to leave that home and carry a small USB adapter that will do the same thing.

So 100-240V input / 12V 2A output

As a non-electrical engineering type I have no clue as to if this even a possibility? Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Personally I'd upgrade to a USB powered drive, which can be had for extremely cheap these days. You can get a 1TB USB drive (which uses a single USB for both data/power) for less than $50. I'm guessing you are using a full 3.5" drive in an external enclosure, which would be difficult to power via USB.

Comment: At 2000 A I bet you want something smaller. At 12 V that's 24 kW and would be enough to run a small data centre. More likely it's rated at 2000 **mA** or 2 A.

Comment: Normal USB can't pull 24W, try 10W

Comment: Are you wanting a 5V (USB) input to 12V output converter? | Is the 5V from a "USB" powerbank? If yes/yes - this can be done with a suitably rated powerbank.

Comment: How big is your external drive?

Answer (score 0):

The cost of  Flash memory in $/MB has dropped rapidly with technology as they have squeezed more analog memory bits per cell and shrunk the cell size.

What was once $50/GB not long ago, is now $50/TB and in some cases $12 for 2TB, more or less.  1TB=1000GB

So no need for a fast heavy HDD for backup unless you have other specs TBD.

Comment: The hardrive is 1TB; not sure why that matters.

Comment: If you get 8TB USB cheaper than a power supply, you can backup 8 times